# C# WPF always fails to connect mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have a problem to connect mysql database   the password is correct

here e example of my .cs

```
 private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string myConnectionString = "Server=ip-adress;Port=3306;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;Database=db-name;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);


        try
        {
            conn.Open();


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        conn.Close();

    }
```

but it give me this in debugger

- IsPasswordExpired = 'conn.IsPasswordExpired' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
- ServerThread    'conn.ServerThread' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'  int {System.NullReferenceException}
- ServerVersion   'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' string {System.NullReferenceException}

What does it mean !

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you can connect to your SQL server via WorkBench or the cmd line?

Answer (score 0):

This error is return becouse you havent changed password for long time it's  Password expiration policy in `MySQL Server.`

> This new system variable defines how long the passwords will be
>   considered valid since they were last changed.  The default is 360
>   days (12 moons?), so passwords will expire roughly every year.

You can change default setting, call `ALTER USER` and disable it.

```
mysql> ALTER USER test_exp@localhost PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

Comment: i change my password but it dont connect ----- :(

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [ConnectionStrings.Com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for the right connection string.

Comment: i know thanks i try the same as from the site but it dont want to work! :(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this now!

The problem was on phpMyAdmin by my Server Provider , they have blocked connections from out their i have calls to them to give me access from my ip and now it works perfectly!